# NetBeans ubuntu font monospaced plane 15 for Eclipse

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, eclipse, netbeans

I use NetBeans IDE for Java web development, and I really enjoy NetBeans Monospaced font for Ubuntu. But now I started using Eclipse for Android projects and I would like to know if there's anyway of setting that font for Eclipse. At the Eclipse "fonts and colors" settings for java there is only one Monospace available, and not the Monospaced plane which is available for NetBeans 7.1.

This is the NetBeans awesome font I would like to set for Eclipse as well

[image]

This is the current Eclipse font:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the same font (DejaVu Sans Mono), the only different thing between the two applications is the *hinting*.